# Remove 'Add Tags' from Activity View Controller - Share

Tags: ios, swift

I have a CSV file which I want to share in my app. My problem is that I see a 'Add Tags' option which I don't know what it is - tried to google and SO it but haven't found anything. Is it possible to deactivate that option? Or, what should be the purpose of it exactly? I am aware of the excludedActivityTypes attribute, but I didn't find anything related to this there.
When I tap on 'Add Tags', it's like something would try to come up (present) but it automatically dismisses.

```
            do {
                let path = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                let fileURL = path.appendingPathComponent("Export.csv")
                try csvExport.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)
                vc.excludedActivityTypes = [.addToReadingList, .assignToContact, .markupAsPDF, .openInIBooks, .saveToCameraRoll]
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } catch {
                print("Error creating file")
            }
```

Comment: Hey! I faced the same breakable one, did you find how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You see the 'Add Tags' option because you are saving the csv to the document directory. If you change `.documentsDirectory` to `.cachesDirectory` the 'Add Tags' option will not be present in the Activity View Controller.

'Add tags' is used to assign tags to files in iCloud Drive - to see the functionality working correctly, click the 'Add Tags' button when sharing a file from within an Apple app (Files, Numbers, Pages etc) on an iOS device.